# How to fetch filename from url [Flutter][Dio]

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

This is My code snippet instead of mypdf.pdf i want to get filename from the url like in android app development,since I'm new in flutter i have no idea can anyone help me

```
Future<void> downloadPDF() async {
Dio dio = Dio();

try {
  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  await dio.download(pdfurl, "${dir.path}/mypdf.pdf",
      onProgress: (rec, total) {

    setState(() {
      downloading = true;
      progressString = ((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
    });
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

setState(() {
  downloading = false;
  progressString = "Completed";
});
print("Download completed");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try it ?

```
File file = new File("/dir1/dir2/file.ext");
String basename = basename(file.path);
# file.ext
```

for more details https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: Thank You So much @noureldien i was actually thinking retrieving filename from httpheader but this method is simple only need to pass url to that File() Cool..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `substring` and `lastIndexOf` methods:

```
 final url = "http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
 final filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will take your pdfurl and get the filename so you don't have to use mypdf.pdf:

```
final myUri = Uri.parse(pdfurl);
final fileName = basename(myUri.path);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.